# How to check if the channel is still working in streadway/amqp RabbitMQ client?

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm using [`github.com/streadway/amqp`](https://github.com/streadway/amqp) for my program. How should I make sure that the channel I'm using for consumption and/or production is still working, before re-initializing it?

For example, in ruby, I could simply do:

```
bunny_client = Bunny.new({....})
bunny_client.start
```

to start the client, and

```
if not bunny_client or bunny_client.status != :connected
    # re-initialize the client
```

How to do this with `streadway/amqp` client?

Comment: Have you had a look in the examples? The example consumer is at https://github.com/streadway/amqp/blob/master/examples/simple-consumer/consumer.go

Comment: @Intermernet yes I did look at the above example, but couldn't readlly figure out how to simply check if my channel is still working. Maybe I'm missing something pretty obvious. I would appreciate if you could help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`QueueDeclare`](http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.QueueDeclare) and [`QueueInspect`](http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.QueueInspect) functions may provide equivalent functionality. According to the docs:

[`QueueInspect`](http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.QueueInspect):

> Use this method to check how many unacknowledged messages reside in the queue and how many consumers are receiving deliveries and whether a queue by this name already exists.
>
> If the queue by this name exists, use Channel.QueueDeclare check if it is declared with specific parameters.
>
> If a queue by this name does not exist, an error will be returned and the channel will be closed.

[`QueueDeclare`](http://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.QueueDeclare):

> QueueDeclare declares a queue to hold messages and deliver to consumers. Declaring creates a queue if it doesn't already exist, or ensures that an existing queue matches the same parameters.

It looks like there's some good info regarding `Durable` queues (survive server restarts) in those docs as well.

Comment: how? these methods provide information about the Queue, not the channel isn't it? I've to check if the CHANNEL is still up, i.e. no error has occurred on a channel...

Answer (score -1):

I have worked around most connectivity issues by trial and error seeing which patterns will work and which won't. I think the best method is to flag a channel when using it (on error). If it fails to publish it gets flagged as well on library side. The errors that are received from server automatically terminate the channel anyways so it just tells my channel pool to rebuild channels when flagged.

You can use my library in golang as an example to create a connection/channelpool and how I flag channels on error.

https://github.com/houseofcat/turbocookedrabbit