# How to detect error when reading from RabbitMQ queue

Tags: go, error-handling, rabbitmq

I'm reading messages from RabbitMQ queue like this:

```
messages, err := channel.Consume(
    queue,  // queue
    queue,  // consumer - same as queue
    false,  // auto-ack
    false,  // exclusive
    false,  // no-local
    false,  // no-wait
    nil)    // args
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

loop:   
for {
    select {
    case cmd := <-cmdChannel:
        if cmd == cmdStop {
            break loop
        }
    case message := <-messages:
        go process(message)
    }
}
```

There could be situations when reading from `messages` fail, like network error, or RabbitMQ's channel was invalidated due to an error. How to detect such errors and get relevant error message?

Comment: Related, details about error handling and `NotifyClose`: [How to check if the channel is still working in streadway/amqp RabbitMQ client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108426/how-to-check-if-the-channel-is-still-working-in-streadway-amqp-rabbitmq-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `streadway/amqp`, this is probably what you are looking for https://godoc.org/github.com/streadway/amqp#Channel.NotifyClose

> #### func (*Channel) NotifyClose
>
> `func (ch *Channel) NotifyClose(c chan *Error) chan *Error`
>
> NotifyClose registers a listener for when the server sends a channel
> or connection exception in the form of a Connection.Close or
> Channel.Close method. Connection exceptions will be broadcast to all
> open channels and all channels will be closed, where channel
> exceptions will only be broadcast to listeners to this channel.
>
> The chan provided will be closed when the Channel is closed and on a
> graceful close, no error will be sent.